# CMake: correctly linking system library using gcc

Tags: gcc, cmake, clang

I have a static libary mylib that depends on the math library.

If I first link mylib with math and then to my executable it works:

```
add_executable(myapp main.c)
target_link_libraries(mylib m)
target_link_libraries(myapp mylib)
```

But if I do the linking directly with the executable it fails when using gcc (with clang it works!)

```
add_executable(myapp main.c)
target_link_libraries(myapp m mylib)
```

Why does this make any difference?
I thought that it is anyway not possible to link libraries together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using cmake's `target_link_libraries` it does not mean you will link anything. It rather will create a dependency between a `target` and a `library` of type/action `link`.

I guess that the actually build line of the first example will result in something like that:

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.o -lmylib -lm
```

and the second one

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.o -lm -lmylib
```

. If `mylib` has references to `m` the second example (might) not link.

Try to run `make VERBOSE=1` and study the command-line of the link-process to really understand what's happening. The linker of clang is maybe intelligent and waits for all calls to be linked before actually dropping a library during the link-process.

Comment: I think you are right - gcc seems to drop libraries during the link if they are not supplied after the binary.
If I change the command to `target_link_libraries(myapp mylib m)` it works!

Comment: Did you use make VERBOSE=1 with clang?

Answer (score 0):

When using `target_link_libraries` it matters in which order you specify linked libraries.

This does not work when using gcc (at least in v4.6.3):

```
target_link_libraries(myapp m mylib)
```

while this works:

```
target_link_libraries(myapp mylib m)
```

So all libraries mylib depends on have to come **after** mylib.

If you track down the actual linker invocation with `make VERBOSE=1` you will find this for the broken example:

```
gcc main.c.o  -o luatest -rdynamic -lm mylib.a
```

and this for the working one:

```
gcc main.c.o  -o luatest -rdynamic mylib.a -lm
```

Invoking clang with the exact same parameters works in both cases!

So @PatrickB seems to be right:

> The linker of clang is maybe intelligent and waits for all calls to be
>   linked before actually dropping a library during the link-process.

Comment: You should probably mark @Patrick B.'s answer as correct then :-)